# Query gives empty result if I check whether the date 2019-01-12 falls with in a December to January date range

Tags: mysql, date, laravel-5, eloquent, date-range

I'm creating an basic Zodiac signs app and I got stuck at this issue.
Basically, I just want to check if today falls between a particular date   range in the mysql table.

NOTE (IGNORE THE YEAR 2019. I just added that for querying convenience)
This is my table:
[Zodia Signs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAyIX.png)

```
 $date = "2019-03-09"
    $zodiacSign =   DB::table('zodiac_signs')
        ->where(function ($query) use($date){
            $query->where('from_date', '<=', $date)
                  ->where('to_date', '>=', $date);
        })->get();
```

Every date except the date between 2019-12-22 and 2019-01-19 is working as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

```
+-----+--------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
| id  |    name      |      symbol       |    icon     | from_date   |  to_date    |     description      |     created_at       |     updated_at       | deleted_at |
+-----+--------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
|  2  | Aries        | The Ram           | NULL        | 2019-03-21  | 2019-04-19  |                      | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  3  | Taurus       | The Bull          | NULL        | 2019-04-20  | 2019-05-20  |                      | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  4  | Gemini       | The Twins         | NULL        | 2019-05-21  | 2019-06-20  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  5  | Cancer       | The Crab          | NULL        | 2019-06-21  | 2019-07-22  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  6  | Leo          | The Lion          | NULL        | 2019-07-23  | 2019-08-22  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  7  | Virgo        | The Virgin        | NULL        | 2019-08-23  | 2019-09-22  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  8  | Libra        | The Scales        | NULL        | 2019-09-23  | 2019-10-22  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
|  9  | Scorpio      | The Scorpion      | NULL        | 2019-10-23  | 2019-11-21  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
| 10  | Sagittarius  | The Archer        | NULL        | 2019-11-22  | 2019-12-21  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
| 11  | Capricorn    | The Goat          | NULL        | 2019-12-22  | 2019-01-19  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
| 12  | Aquarius     | The Water Bearer  | NULL        | 2019-01-20  | 2019-02-18  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
| 13  | Pisces       | The Fishes        | NULL        | 2019-02-19  | 2019-03-20  | NULL                 | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | 2019-07-17 03:09:07  | NULL       |
+-----+--------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: You know that `2019-01-19 < 2019-12-22`?

Comment: yes. I understand what you meant. 
But how do I fix it?  How do I change the db values to fix this issue? 0_o

Comment: Are you asking how to [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) an existing value in DB?

Comment: No. I know that ! I just want to get the result Capricon if the the given date is say 2019-01-03 @PaulSpiegel Did you understand? Do you want me to explain more :)

Comment: Should it work for any year?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes. Exactly.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Did you get it?

Comment: I guess I get it. Please post the data as text table in a code block. So we can C&P it.

Comment: Added the data as an html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and lazy solution is to add Capricorn twice. Once to be part of the start of the year (starts in 2018) and once for the end of the year (ends in 2020). If it's not desirable to have zodiacs appear twice, you will need to update your query to special-case the zodiac that crosses the year line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean for your from_date to be 2018-12-22, not 2019-12-22? (or maybe the to_date should be 2020. You get the idea. December of year N and January of year N+1).

Comment: No. I'm correct. I'm just so confused. I think my date range is way wrong for that Capricon.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a different logic to find the user's Zodiac sign. The approach could be like this, assume that the user's date of birth is December 25. so check the month (December) with your database it could be either `Sagittarius` or `Capricorn`. then check the Day (25), as day is > 22 then the Zodiac sign would be `Capricorn`.

if i break down into steps,

1. set the range with month and day only, do not add year. check the
2. user's month first and find which two could be his/her sign check
3. check the day to finalize the decision

You may try a different table structure to accommodate this approach.